# Setting Up User Permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, webforms, user-permissions

What is the best way to set-up page permissions based off username?  Here is my predicament:
I am needing to set-up user security and want to do this right from the start (why I ask).

I will have users that are (and these names can be changed) in one of these groups:

- fulladmin
- privelageduser
- employee
- temp
- contract

and will be granting access to specific pages based off of what group the username falls into.
However, I will have a few one-offs where a member of say `privelageduser` will need access to one of the `fulladmin` pages, but only that 1 page, not the full pages that a `fulladmin` gets.
So for example, let's say a full admin has rights to pages 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 and a `privelageduser` has rights to pages 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 *BUT* this one specific username that is in the `privelageduser` group needs access to pages 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 11.

And due to the 1-offs I can't just grant a "securitylevel" flag of "FA", "PU", "EM", "TE", "CO".

Comment: As well as telling us if this is MVC or WebForms; also what identity or membership provider are you using?

Comment: IMO there is no `best way` to solve such problems, but there are many "good ways" -> what have you thought of so far? What would you prefer how it could work?

Comment: @ChrFin - I was thinking of setting up access to pages based off the security flag.  But wasn't sure how to handle the one-off cases where a user doesn't really fall into any of the flags listed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.Net has the [Membership Provider Doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049(v=vs.110).aspx) you can use.

Another option, might be more top heavy, you could try would be to create roles, groups, users using your database tables.  Once those are created you could implement custom logic for the above utilizing the business layer of your application.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MVC you could try using the [Authorize attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). That allows you to authorize by username and / or by role:

```
[Authorize(Users = "Tom, Chris")]
 public ActionResult SpecificUserOnly()
 {
     return View();
 }


[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, SuperAdmin")]
public ActionResult AdministratorsOnly()
{
    return View();
}
```

You can even [create a customized authorize attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707357%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) if you have very specific needs.

Comment: Will [OAuth](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/15/oauth-openid-support-for-webforms-mvc-and-webpages.aspx) work for [Web Forms](http://sanderstechnology.com/2014/a-lightweight-implementation-owin-oauth-for-asp-net-web-forms-using-visual-studio-2013-part-1/12875/), yes.